# How do I add proper default IPv6 routing in Android?

Tags: internet, router, ipv6

I see many possibilities to add IPv6 routing. Namely, to point out the proper table (device-specific, the same as 'dev' parameter for `ip` command, local, no table at all).

How to do it exactly?